# Principal argument null for anonymous user in ResourceServer

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-web

I have an extremely simple sample app here: https://github.com/timtebeek/anonymous-principal

Relevant bits copied below:

[`ResourceConfig.java`](https://github.com/timtebeek/anonymous-principal/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/timtebeek/anonymous/principal/ResourceConfig.java)

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().denyAll();

        // Anonymous user should authenticate as guest for authorization
        http.anonymous().principal("guest");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId("myresource");
    }
}
```

[`DemoApplication`](https://github.com/timtebeek/anonymous-principal/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/timtebeek/anonymous/principal/DemoApplication.java)

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@SuppressWarnings("static-method")
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/principal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(final Principal user) {
        Assert.notNull(user);
        return user.getName();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authprincipal", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(@AuthenticationPrincipal final String user) {
        Assert.notNull(user);
        return user;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/authentication", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        Assert.notNull(auth);
        return auth.getName();
    }
}
```

In this setup both `/authprincipal` and `/authentication` work, but `/principal` fails when the user is not authenticated, as the principal argument is `null`. I'd wanted to use the plain `Principal` rest method argument with my anonymous users as well, as that gives me the cleanest code.

What can I do to make `Principal` argument in my rest methods work for anonymous users?

Comment: @AuthenticationPrincipal User user is this work ?

Comment: @ali it should, provided you have your UserDetailsProvider setup correctly. Also see the updated Github link and [test results](https://travis-ci.org/timtebeek/anonymous-principal)